# Removing unnecessary wordpress files

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, xml-rpc

I want to consider removing the next `<link>` files from the `<head>` section of my website:

```
...wp-json
...xmlrpc.php?rsd
...wlwmanifest.xml
```

But I don't really know how would this may affect my wordpress site - I don't use any plugins at all - and how to actually remove them efficiently, because while googling, I notice there's some "headers"(I think HTTP-Headers) that remain after removing the `xmlrpc.php?rds`, for example. But perhaps it may affect in some other way too. I can't tell.

I also found the following lines of code, to remove the `wlwmanifest` and `wp-json`:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rest_output_link_wp_head');
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_oembed_add_discovery_links');
remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'rest_output_link_header', 11, 0 );
```

It does remove the files `wlwmanifest` and `wp-json`, but the `xml` is remained and as I know now, it's dangerous from the sense of the hacker-attacks. Also, I don't really know if I should use this code above or should something else instead.

Hopefully you could help me with this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use any 3rd services such as [XMLRPC](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com) | [REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org) | [oEmbed](http://oembed.com) |  [Windows Live Writer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Live_Writer), removing those lines/headers doesn't affect anything to your site.

Those lines of code is the best way to archive what you want. To remove `xmlrpc.php?rds`, you need another line:

```
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
```

Put all of them in your `functions.php` or some where so that they are called before the [wp_head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_head/) action is fired.

Comment: perhaps you may know why am I still able to see the `xmlrpc.php?rsd` file at the same address if I type it manually in the address bar? The whole idea was to remove this for be less vulnerable for attacks @Dan9